# Rails 3 - Multiple database with joins condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, join

**My environment:** Ruby 1.9.2p290, Rails 3.0.9 and RubyGem 1.8.8

unfortunately I have an issue when come across multiple database.

**The situation is this:** I have two model connect with two different database and also establishing association between each other. 
database connection specifying in each model, look likes

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.establish_connection "lab"
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.establish_connection "main"
  has_many :visits
end
```

I got an error when meet following scenario

```
@visits = Visit.joins(:patient)
```

Errors: Mysql2::Error: Table 'lab.patients' doesn't exist: SELECT `visits`.* FROM `visits` INNER JOIN `patients` ON `patients`.`id` IS NULL

Here 'patients' table is in 'main' database and 'visits' table in 'lab' database
I doubt when executing the code, that Rails is considering 'patients' table is part of 'lab' database [which holds 'visits' table].

Comment: See [Issue #539](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/539) for additional information

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this is the most elegant solution, but I did get this to work by defining `self.table_name_prefix` to explicitly return the database name.

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.table_name_prefix
    renv = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || ENV['RACK_ENV']
    (renv.empty? ? "lab." : "lab_#{renv}.")
  end

  self.establish_connection "lab"
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.table_name_prefix
    renv = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || ENV['RACK_ENV']
    (renv.empty? ? "main." : "main_#{renv}.")
  end

  self.establish_connection "main"
  has_many :visits
end
```

I'm still working through all the details when it comes to specifying the join conditions, but I hope this helps.

Comment: This is the way to go if the two databases are on the same machine. Well done.

Answer (score 7):

Might be cleaner to do something like this:

```
  def self.table_name_prefix
    "#{Rails.configuration.database_configuration["#{Rails.env}"]['database']}."
  end
```

That will pull the appropriate database name from your database.yml file

Answer (score 3):

Or even

```
def self.table_name_prefix
   self.connection.current_database+'.'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your 2nd database on another machine? You can always do as suggested in this other question:

[MySQL -- Joins Between Databases On Different Servers Using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832787/mysql-joins-between-databases-on-different-servers-using-python)

Comment: No. both database are in same machine. Rails looks appropriate database when calling visits and Patient separately. 'visits= Visit.first.patient' and vise versa works fine. Problem only when joining both models.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `self.table_name_prefix` as proposed by others, but you can define it a little more cleanly like this:

```
self.table_name_prefix "#{Rails.configuration.database_configuration["#{Rails.env}"]['database']}."
```

alternatively you could also use this:

```
self.table_name_prefix "#{connection.current_database}."
```

You have to keep in mind that the latter will execute a query `SELECT DATABASE() as db` the first time that class is loaded.