# How to JOIN tables of two different databases in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4.1.5
How to JOIN tables of two different databases in Ruby on Rails.

I have a Model(Users) in DB1 and another model(Assets) in DB2.
Association between Users and Assets is: User has_many assets
and Asset belongs_to User.

Query:
I want to Join these two tables, right now I'm using raw sql query in my application.
"SELECT * FROM DB1.users user JOIN DB2.assets asset ON asset.user_id = user.id"

Is there any better solution in RoR?

Comment: Are the databases in the same database engine on the same server? Does the database user have access to both databases?

Comment: Yes, both the Databases are on the same server and user have access to both DB.

Comment: Did you try the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968221/rails-3-multiple-database-with-joins-condition)?