# Connetions with another database and server on subquery

Tags: php, sql

How can I connect with `db1`, `server1` with `sub query` ?
Thanks!

```
$link1 = mysql_connect("server1","user1","pas1");
mysql_select_db('db1', $link1);
$link2 = mysql_connect("server2","user2","pas2") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db2", $link2) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="SELECT db2.`e`.`entity_id` , db2.a.value AS klantnr, db2.b.value AS    voornaam,db2.c.value AS achternaam, db2.`t`.`value` AS telfnr, db2.ce.email FROM     db2.`tablename` e LEFT OUTER JOIN db2.customer_entity_varchar a ON db2.a.entity_id = db2.e.parent_id AND db2.a.attribute_id = '133' WHERE db2.ce.email NOT IN(SELECT db1.email_addresses.email_address FROM db1.tablename) AND db2.a.value IN (SELECT db1.accounts_cstm.custid_c FROM db1.accounts_cstm ) GROUP BY db2.ce.email";
$result = mysql_query($sql,????) or die(mysql_error());
```

I have another solution (way) but I get this error(Operand should contain 1 column(s))

```
$link1 =mysql_connect("server1","user1","pas1");
mysql_select_db('db1', $link1);
$link2 = mysql_connect("server2","user2","pas2") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db2", $link2) or die(mysql_error());
$query="SELECT email_addresses.email_address FROM db1.tablename";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link1) or die(mysql_error()); 
$select=array();
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$select[]=$row["email_address"];
$select = "('" . implode ("','", $select) . "')";
mysql_query("set     sql_big_selects=1",$moonen_link); 
$sql="SELECT `e`.`entity_id` , a.value AS klantnr, b.value AS voornaam, c.value AS achternaam, `t`.`value` AS telfnr, ce.email FROM `tablename` e LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_entity_varchar a ON a.entity_id = e.parent_id AND a.attribute_id = '133' WHERE ce.email NOT IN($select) GROUP BY ce.email"; $result = mysql_query($sql,$link2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `server1` and `server2` are different servers, correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect multiple database,servers in mysql and query from both tables of each other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584810/how-to-connect-multiple-database-servers-in-mysql-and-query-from-both-tables-of)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL -- Joins Between Databases On Different Servers Using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832787/mysql-joins-between-databases-on-different-servers-using-python)

Comment: Yes server1 and server2 are different servers

Comment: You can use federation connection, its table that come from other db.

Answer (score -1):

I think your "user1" should have access (privilege) to both database if they are on the same mysql server.

Then you could connect to one database with

```
$link1 = mysql_connect("server1","user1","pas1");
mysql_select_db('db1', $link1);
```

And then do your  request on both server with $link1:

```
 $sql="SELECT db2.`e`.`entity_id` , db2.a.value AS klantnr, db2.b.value AS     voornaam,db2.c.value AS achternaam, db2.`t`.`value` AS telfnr, db2.ce.email FROM     db2.`tablename` e LEFT OUTER JOIN db2.customer_entity_varchar a ON db2.a.entity_id = db2.e.parent_id AND db2.a.attribute_id = '133' WHERE db2.ce.email NOT IN(SELECT db1.email_addresses.email_address FROM db1.tablename) AND db2.a.value IN (SELECT db1.accounts_cstm.custid_c FROM db1.accounts_cstm ) GROUP BY db2.ce.email";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$link1) or die(mysql_error());
```

Should be ok

Comment: Where is the connection with the db2 and server2? I want the connection with db1,server1 on the        (SELECT db1.accounts_cstm.custid_c FROM db1.accounts_cstm )

Comment: if the databases are on the same server you could connect to other database without create  a new link.
Like DanFromGermany said you're on 2 different servers.
so my answer is not wrong but unappropriate to your case. Sorry