# Join between two databases of different server

Tags: mysql

I have two databases on different server : server A and server B

server A have table  : user 
server B have table  : userProfile

Is there any way by which I can join user to userProfile ?

Comment: [Joins between databases on different servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832787/mysql-joins-between-databases-on-different-servers-using-python/5832973#5832973).

Comment: Please refer this:


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers][1]


 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers

Comment: I think its for sql-server .. Is mysql support this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to add server A as linked server to Server B or vice versa to access both the tables and join in any of the server A or server B.

Comment: IN mysql is it possible to have linked server ? how ?

Comment: @Amrish Prajapati In MySQL - no.

Comment: refer this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370970/how-to-create-linked-server-mysql