# Match rows together from two different tables in two separate databases

Tags: php, mysql

I have two databases, one with a table called `v_esd` and the other call `channel_did`

in `v_esd` there is a column called `number` and in `channel_did` a column called `did`

i want to search through the `channel_did` table and match the `did` column value with the `number` column in the `v_esd` table. if there is no match, display the results.

i have 2 different connection strings as they are 2 completely separate databases

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `database1`.`v_esd` JOIN `database2`.`channel_did` ON `database1`.`v_esd`.`number` = `database2`.`channel_did`.`did`
```

this should work, maybe you can shorten this Statement by using 'AS' in the query

Comment: i am using a connection string like $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("db_name",$conn); so i have two of these, the second one is not called $conn so how does it know what to connect to when running the SQL Query?

Comment: do you mean, you have two mysql-connections or two databases? (by the way i would use the mysqli-functions instead of the mysql-functions, they are newer and work better)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM db1.channel_did.did WHERE did NOT IN(SELECT number FROM db2.v_esd )
```

Just drop the select db statement,and if they are on the same server your connection will be able to access any db on that server.
Nope,no possibility to do that in one query,if they are on separate server.

```
$rs = mysql_query($query1);

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
      if($i<$numrows){
        $data1[$i] = $row1;
    }
  }

$rs2 = mysql_query($query2);
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs2)) {
      if($i<$numrows){
        $data2[$i] = $row2;
    }
  }
$uniquevalues = array_merge(array_diff($row1, $row2), array_diff($row2, $row1))
```

Something like this

Comment: they are on 2 different servers

Comment: Well then you have a problem.

Comment: Whats the structure of those tables, what you need from them and which one has more records?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832787/mysql-joins-between-databases-on-different-servers-using-python