# How to connect with multi mysql db

Tags: php, mysqli

how do i configure my php connection file to connect with 2 or more database ?

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    {
session_start();
}
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$uid=$_SESSION['user_id'];
$connect['database'] ='mydb';

/** MySQL database username */
$connect['user']='root';
/** MySQL database password */
$connect['password']='';
/** MySQL hostname */
$connect['host']='localhost';
$host= mysqli_connect($connect['host'],$connect['user'],$connect['password'],$connect['database']);
?>
```

Comment: You can use `mysqli_connect` for each connection, but you can also access different databases on the same server by prefixing the table names with the database name (assuming the privileges are correct) - something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296500/mysqli-join-tables-from-2-different-databases

Comment: can you configure it for example as i want to connect all tables not a specific one

Comment: It may be better to create an example of what you are trying to achieve and why you are doing it that way.

Comment: I want to login with single php code for to diffrent db , the all db tables are same but have the diffrent  data .by this i can save the server space as i am using three code file for the three db but after this implimentation i have to use only one code to a access all three data base.