# Yii2: Is it possible 2 databases query at once with JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, yii2

I have project on Yii2. I have 2 databases. I need to execute command with `join` like

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`id`;
```

..where `table1` is from `db1` and `table2` from `db2`. notice: `db2` is on another server.

```
        'db1' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1',
            'username' => '...',
            'password' => '...',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'db2' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=anotherserver.com;dbname=db2',
            'username' => '...',
            'password' => '...',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ]
```

**Q1:** How to do that on clean mysql/php? on Yii2?
.. or the only way is to fetch results from `table1` and `table2` separated and then loop to compare `id`?

**Q2:** How to compare `id` in yii2 in `dataProvider`?

```
$query = Table1::find();
$query2 = Table2::find();
// how compare id?

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL -- Joins Between Databases On Different Servers Using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832787/mysql-joins-between-databases-on-different-servers-using-python)  Ignore the python part - this is a mysql problem.

Comment: It is a yii2 problem because of the way active record works, by default, yii2 uses a connection which specifies a database. To use relations between two databases, you have to specify the db in the model table defintion.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to perform a JOIN between two different databases in MySQL. However, Yii's ActiveRecord relation system doesn't use JOINs to retrieve related data, but a separate "IN" query, which allows it to retrieve relational data across different databases or even different DBMS types.

```
class Table1 extends ActiveRecord {
    public static function getDb()
    {
        return Yii::$app->db1;
    }

    public function getTable2()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Table2::class, ['id' => 'id']);
    }
}

class Table2 extends ActiveRecord {
    public static function getDb()
    {
        return Yii::$app->db2;
    }
}

$query = Table1::find()->with('table2');
```

Comment: It is possible, but requires specifying the schema with the table name in the model assuming both databases are on the same server. The other option is federated tables.

Comment: NOT True, see federated engine answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch result of first table and second table separately then perform the join operation in php.

But if the data is huge it will take huge amount of time

Answer (score 0):

### Using Federated Table

**MySQL Example**

[image: Using Federated Engine]

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

See [Creating a FEDERATED Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create-connection.html)

> The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the remote (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables.

### Same Connection w/ different Schema

```
db_conn---> db1 -> tableA
        |
        |-> db2 -> tableB
```

If both databases are on the same db connection instance, then this is easily done if you specify the schema with the table name like so:

```
Class TableA extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'databaseA.tableA';
    }
    ....
}

Class TableB extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'databaseB.tableB';
    }
    ....
}
```

Now you can do sub-query as well:

```
$subQuery = TableB::find()
    ->select('id')
    ->where(['column' => 'criteria'])
    ->column();

$query = TableA::find()
    ->join(['b' => $subQuery], 'b.column_pk = a.column_fk')
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create view for the table1 in db2 and take the join with that view.
but as you have mentioned that db2 is on another server then taking the join will be costly operation.